# How can I add FacesMessage during page load? Using @PostConstruct does not seem to work

Tags: jsf, message, pageload, postconstruct

In a backing bean's @PostConstruct method, I make a call to an EJB which might return some messages that I want to display on the page via p:messages. However, even if I add the FacesMessages e.g. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(...), p:messages is not being updated with the FacesMessages.

If I instead invoke the call to the EJB on an action from the page (say a user clicks a button on the page which invokes a method that calls the EJB and then adds the FacesMessage(s)), then the messags show up using p:messages as expected.

How do I add Faces Messages during @PostConstruct and have them show up when the page is initially rendered?

Code:

Page1Controller.java:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Page1Controller
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new FacesMessage("Test Message from @PostConstruct"));
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
            return "Some Value";
    }

    public void triggerMessage(ActionEvent event)
    {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                    new FacesMessage("Test Message from Trigger Button"));      
    }

}
```

page1.xhtml

```
   <h:form>
        <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{page1Controller.value}"/>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Trigger Message" 
                         actionListener="#{page1Controller.triggerMessage}"/>  
   </h:form>
```

Comment: Note-- if invoke the same method (to call the EJB, etc) using the f:event type="preRenderView" listener directive, then the FacesMessage is appropriately updated. Should I just do this?

Comment: Using Mojarra 2.1.7, Primefaces 3.2 (latest stable).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That can happen when the message component is rendered *before* the message is added.

In your specific example, the bean is referenced for the first time by the `<h:outputText>` component and thus constructed for the first time at that moment. But the `<h:outputText>` component appears in your specific example *after* the `<p:messages>` component, so the `<p:messages>` component is already rendered and thus it's too late to show the message.

You need to make sure somehow that the message is added *before* the message component is rendered. One way is using `<f:viewAction>`. It runs during `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase which is before `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase. Thus it runs before *any* component is rendered. A perfect opportunity thus.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
public void onload() {
    // Add message here instead of in @PostConstruct.
}
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)

Comment: Thanks... is an alternative that in the @PostConstruct method, after I've added the FacesMessage, I then access the Messages component (via ViewRoot.findComponent) and tell the messages component to "rerender" itself? (Is this possible?) If possible, is this a better approach than preRenderView or moving output text above p:messages?

Comment: No, that's not possible. As to the proper approach, well that depends on the concrete functional requirement. Under what condition exactly do you need to add a faces message? When some request parameter is invalid or so? If so, you should rather have used `<f:viewParam>` for this. If not, then the `<f:event type="preRenderView">` would be fine (which is better to be replaced by a more sane `<f:viewAction>` when you get the chance to upgrade to JSF 2.2 later).

Comment: Now, this is a real frustration with JSF... It shouldn't be this hard to get a message displayed on the screen.

Comment: I don't understand this :"the <p:messages> is rendered before the managed bean is constructed for the first time. It's then too late to add the message." Why is it too late ? Note that I don't have any issue with I'm just curious.

Comment: @CED: Plain java 'example': Suppose you have an array with 5 elements and iterate over it and do a `System.out.println` of each (rendereing it) and then add an additional element. That won't be displayed then. And this is not a JSF specific problem like an 8 year old comment suggests. Plain JSP with EL and whatever js UI framework is used has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the error and then display it at the end of loading the page using a remoteCommand of primefaces with autorun = true mode.
In my case I have a viewScope and in xhtml I show the list of values that are loaded in the @PostConstruct. If an Exception is generated I will save it to the sample at the end of the page load if it exists using the remoteCommand.

```
private ArrayList<Exception> postConstucError = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void validarAcceso() {
    /**
     * verificar permisos a la vista de coeficientes
     */
    try {
            this.init() //load data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        this.postConstucError.add(e);
    }
}

 public void showPostConstructError() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.postConstucError.size(); i++) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Error al cargar datos iniciales: " + postConstucError.get(i).getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: showPostConstructError() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

xhtml code

```
  <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/> 
  <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand id="rcomerror" name="showError" process="@this"  autoRun="true"
                         actionListener="#{mBPresentNinos.showPostConstructError()}" />  
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Creative solution... And how does your `showPostConstructError()` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

For me using preRenderView event to display message on form init was a messages-hell. So I created very simple "component" to keep static messages. For this example only one error message is supported.

**staticMessage.xhtml:**

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
             rendered="#{rendered}">
    <div id="staticMessage" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite">
        <div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-messages-error-icon"/>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="ui-messages-error-summary">#{value}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Including messages:

```
 <ui:include src="/template/components/staticMessage.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="rendered"value="#{beanMB.staticMessagesRendered}"/>
     <ui:param name="value" value="Place your message here."/>
 </ui:include>
```