# Only display messages with: Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I am trying to display simple messages with `<p:messages/>` but only I've got is the message of development mode of MyFaces. I will explain.

On my XHTML page, I have the following code to diplay my messages:

```
<div class="messagePanel">
    <p:messages id="msgCalls" 
                for="msgCalls"
                showDetail="true"
                showSummary="true"
                autoUpdate="true"
                closable="true" />
</div>
```

On my bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        this.linhaCelularId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("linhaCelularId");

        if (this.linhaCelularId == null || this.linhaCelularId.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Messages.addGlobalError(MENSAGEM_GLOBAL, "Nenhum celular especificado para listagem de ligações");
        }
        else {
            this.linhaCelularTitular = getLinhaCelularTitularService().getById(Long.parseLong(this.linhaCelularId));

            if (this.linhaCelularTitular == null) {
                Messages.addGlobalError(MENSAGEM_GLOBAL, "Celular não encontrado!");
            }
            else if (!this.linhaCelularTitular.getResponsavel().getAn8().equals(this.loginMB.getLoggedUser().getAn8())) {
                Messages.addGlobalError(MENSAGEM_GLOBAL, "Você não tem permissão para acessar essa página. Esse erro foi reportado.");
            }
            else {
                this.faturaTitular = getFaturaTitularService().getUltimaFaturaCarregada();
                this.itensFaturaTitular = getFaturaTitularService().getItensFaturaPorCelularFatura(this.linhaCelularTitular, this.faturaTitular);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao buscar ultima fatura carregada", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the message added by `Faces.addGlobalError()` or `Faces.addError()` is not showing by my `<p:messages.../>`. The message only shows up on *Unhandled Messages* of development mode. Take a look when I inspect the HTML:

```
<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" 
    title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages"
    style="color:orange">
    <li>
        <span title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages">Você não tem permissão para acessar essa página. Esse erro foi reportado.</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I already tried some other ways to do:

- Put only `<p:messages/>` and `<h:messages>` on XHTML;
- Tried to use `Faces.addGlobalError()` and `Faces.addError()`;
- Used `FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();`

None of above worked. I don't know what else to do. Currently, I am using MyFaces 2.1.12, Primefaces 4.0 and Omnifaces 1.5.

Comment: Try taking out `for="msgCalls"` from above `<p:messages/>`

Comment: @SRy, Thanks for your reply. I removed `for="msgCalls"` and tried again. No success. I changed `Faces.addGlobalError()` to `Faces.addError()`. No success too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

When I access my XHTML with GET request and parameters, the `@PostConstruct` is not called until "some reference" to the managed bean on page is made. So, the tag `<p:messages />` was placed before the first reference to the managed bean. When the `@PostConstruct` was called, it was already too late to render the messages.

The solution is to put the a `preRenderView` before the tag `<p:messages />` and point to a method. Even to point to an empty method. Tthe managed bean will be constructed before the `<p:messages />` and all messages will be rendered.

Here is a [nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10198243/1675048) about this topic by [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)