# Not able to update "growl" in template from Backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, growl, requestcontext

I have a `template` file which contains primefaces `growl` component. I am using this `template` in another `index.xhtml` file. Now I am trying to add a `FacesMessage` from `backing bean` in `@postconstruct` function. However my `index.xhtml` file is not showing the `growl`.

**template.xhtml**

```
       <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content" class="template-00-startpage clearfix">                  
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />             
            </div>
        </div>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/Template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="leftContent">
            <h:outputText value="#{backingBean.username}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

**backingBean.java**

```
@PostConstruct
private void init(){
    username = "testing it";
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Trying to display this message");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.update("growl");      
}
```

I tried wrapping the `<p:growl>` component in `<h:form id="main">` and then update `main:growl`, however it does not work.

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. Is it necessary to trigger or update `growl` in `.xhtml` file or via `commandButton update="growl"`?

EDIT: My requirement is to use `growl` to display error messages. Therefore I am using it in template and can update it from any backing bean. The way I am trying to implement it is,

- Have `growl` in template. It will get processed before backing bean. Hence will not be displayed.
- An error occured, I will add that error message in `FacesMessage` and update my `growl` in the template file.
- When `growl` is updated, I believe it should get displayed; but is not, which is my problem

Comment: Maybe similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197277/how-can-i-add-faces-messages-during-postconstruct Try adding `<f:event type="preRenderView">` You can also find some information here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37142

Comment: @MathieuCastets Thanks for the links.....I have read the link... if I move my `growl` after the  `h:outputText` it renders `growl`. However, I understand that my `growl` is getting processed before my managed bean, that is why I am trying to update the `growl` again in my backing bean. So if I am updating `growl` in backing bean, i guess it should be displayed or I am wrong?